# For every odd table row, switch table cells with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, drupal-6

I am working in a CMS and have little control of the HTML.  I am relying on jQuery to manipulate this table.  My client wants to alternate the title and image for each row.

The desired layout would look somewhat like this:

```
[Image][Title]
[Title][Image]
[Image][Title]
[Title][Image]
```

This is a simplified version of what I am working with:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="views-field-title"></td>
    <td class="views-field-field-services-image-fid"></td>
    <td class="views-field-value0"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="views-field-title"></td>
    <td class="views-field-field-services-image-fid"></td>
    <td class="views-field-value0"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="views-field-title"></td>
    <td class="views-field-field-services-image-fid"></td>
    <td class="views-field-value0"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="views-field-title"></td>
    <td class="views-field-field-services-image-fid"></td>
    <td class="views-field-value0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I am new to jQuery and have been struggling with .each() functions.  This is as far as I was able to get:

```
$(".views-field-title").after($(".views-field-field-services-image-fid"));
```

Comment: You should really consider doing this backend. Switching around like this with javascript is a terrible solution. drupal should have some way to achive this.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how this would be achieved @OptimusCrime?  My partner builds the sites and I simply theme them and rely on jQuery for visual manipulation this this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to change the order in the odds, just change the order of the childrens

```
 $(function() {
        jQuery.each($(".odd"), function() { 
            $(this).children(":eq(1)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        });
    });
```

Here is the Fiddle with it working. http://jsfiddle.net/77pHb/

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("tr.odd .views-field-field-services-image-fid").after(function () {
    return $(this).prev();
});
```

Here's what's going on:

- The selector returns every "image" column of each odd table row.
- The [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after) function can take a function. That function is executed once for every item in the jQuery object.
- Inside the function we're passing to `.after`, we're returning the element we want to insert *after* the current item we're iterating over. In our case, we want the element directly previous to the one we're looking at (the "title" element). We can retrieve that using [`.prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/10/

Comment: You were thorough with your explanation and your JSFiddle worked but I couldn't get this to work on the site.

Comment: @JCL: Hmm, I wonder what the difference is? Are you using a recent version of jQuery?

Comment: This particular site is running version 1.3.2